# "Set" and explicit "Variant" statement Deprecation?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am relatively new to programming in VB, so please be patient with my frustration.

I am trying to declare a class using VB in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, and I'm following along with a tutorial, but Intellisense keeps messing with my code. Here's something along the lines of what I'm trying to write:

```
Import HYSYS

Dim myVar As Variant
...
Public Class MyClassVB1
    Dim hyContainer As Object
    Public Function Initialize(ByVal Container As Object, ByVal IsRecalling As Boolean) As Long
        Set hyContainer = Container
    End Function
```

However, Visual Studio turns my code into this:

```
Import HYSYS

Dim myVar As VariantType
...
Public Class MyClassVB1
    Dim hyContainer As Object
    Public Function Initialize(ByVal Container As Object, ByVal IsRecalling As Boolean) As Long
        SetAttr() hyContainer = Container
    End Function
```

After arguing with Visual Studio for a while, I finally have the message *Let and Set assignment statements are no longer supported.*

Is there a replacement that I'm supposed to use, or does Visual Studio just assume that I mean `Variant` if I don't explicitly specify a type?

Likewise, do I need to use a keyword or function for variable assignment, or can I treat it like I would in c++ and just write `hyContainer = Container`?

Comment: No keyword required to assign objects instances. VB.NET doesn’t support the Variant data type, use the 'Object' data type. But you should really try to replace any variant in your old code with a specific data type.

Comment: In VB .net just use the equal sign (**=**) to both assign and compare.

Comment: You're using an outdated tutorial. `Variant` has not been part of the VB language for more than 10 years. `Set` is almost as bad.

Comment: The last version of VB that still supported Set and Variant was released *fifteen* years ago.  There are many excellent introductory books that will teach you VB.NET, clearly you want to stop reading whatever you found.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I have to work with this thing to figure out the COM interface to some proprietary software, but I'll look somewhere else for good VB code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set`, as you're using it, is left over from the vb6/vbscript days.

**It no longer works like that in VB.Net**. You never ever use it for assignment.

You may be following an obsolete tutorial. In VB.Net, `Set` is only used as part of a LINQ query.

`Variant` is similar. It is no longer part of the VB language at all, and has not been for *more than 10 years.*

Comment: According to MSDN `Set` 
"declares a Set property procedure used to assign a value to a property". In terms of it being used as part of a LINQ query - you might be thinking about `Let`.